# Connection unrecoverable after short network disconnect

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, entitymanager

I want to use JPA in my tomcat webapplication. Therefore I created my own `Filter` (mentioned in web.xml).

The filter has three methods:

- The `init` method creates an `EntityManagerFactory` and stores it in an instance field (executed at deployment of application)
- The `doFilter` method uses the stored EntityManagerFactory to create an entityManager, start a transaction and close the transaction (and the entityManager) after the request to be processed
- The `destroy` method closes the stored EntityManagerFactory

This mechanism works fine and is quite fast - but **once the database connection is lost, the application cannot recover**.

How can I refresh the EntityManagerFactory, so that it creates a new database connection? Or should I destroy and recreate the EntityManagerFactory? Do I have to run a database query, to check, whether the connection is alive?

My current filter is implemented like this:

```
package entityManagerTest;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/JpaServlet" })
public class JpaFilter implements Filter {

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory .createEntityManager();
        try {
            EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            try {
                request.setAttribute("entityManager", entityManager);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } finally {
                transaction.commit();
            }
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

The servlet looks like that:

```
package entityManagerTest;

import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/JpaServlet"})
public class JpaServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) req.getAttribute("entityManager");

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT 42");
        Object singleResult = query.getSingleResult();

        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.write("DB:"+singleResult);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver:..." />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="x" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="y" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I tried adding a *validationQuery*, but without seeing any change in behaviour:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
<property name="connection.validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
```

When the connection is lost, I'm getting a rollback exception (not suprising):

```
Aug 18, 2015 11:41:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
Aug 18, 2015 11:41:30 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Aug 18, 2015 11:41:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [entityManagerTest.JpaServlet] in context with path [/EntityManagerTests] threw exception
org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    at entityManagerTest.JpaFilter.doFilter(JpaFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:211)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:389)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:1955)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
    ... 22 more
```

But after the network connection is back again, the code still fails with an exception (**even though the connection would be recoverable now**):

```
Aug 18, 2015 11:42:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [entityManagerTest.JpaServlet] in context with path [/EntityManagerTests] threw exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
    at entityManagerTest.JpaFilter.doFilter(JpaFilter.java:24)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Die Verbindung wurde geschlossen.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:389)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1910)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:68)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: The EMF doesn't handle connections ... that is the role of the EntityManager. I don't see you closing an EntityManager in what you wrote

Comment: the easiest solution would be : use a connection pool .. i dont know about web-containers like tomcat but every applcation server offers connection pooling. AFAIR, you can also load a connection-pooling JAR into your webapp-dependencies, declare & use it and all is well.

Comment: @NeilStockton thanks for the hint - I forgot to mention, that I am closing the entityManager in the `doFilter` method.

Comment: How are you telling the provider how to connect to the database?  If it is connecting directly, your provider will have its own options on how to refresh/reconnect connections in the event one dies.  Otherwise, the container's datasource will handle it

Comment: @Chris I'm using Hibernate with JPA. I attached my persistence.xml to show my connection configuration.

Comment: look up connection pool configuration for your JPA provider. All connection pools allow an SQL to be invoked to check if a connection is active and to recreate as necessary.

Comment: Can you show an stack trace of what is happening when you loss the connection?

Comment: @Victor I added the stacktraces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from [the official hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#d0e1756):

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is **not
>   intended for use in a production system**, or even for performance
>   testing. [...] For example, you might like to use c3p0.

You must specify a connection pool datasource. Connection pools usually checks validity of a connection before using it. Here is an example of C3P0 (Connection pool datasource) and Hibernate configuration for connection pooling. I hope it will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

            <!-- I am not exactly sure that which one is correct -->
            <!-- javax.persistence.* or hibernate.connection.* properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver:..."/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="x"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="y"/>


            <!-- Connection Pooling settings -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also you need to add hibernate-c3p0 to your class path.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It works! I used version 4.3.11.Final and c3p0 can restore the connection after a short network disconnect. Thanks!

Comment: So you only change the "persistence.xml" to tell hibernate to use an arbitrary connection pool and that is all?. Your code has no further changes? The problem was the hibernate native connection algorithm? Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Victor since my answer is accepted, I think it solved the problem. And about confirmation, I think reference to official hibernate documentation is all that I can. I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: yes, but please, tell me something... did you have to change something on your code or no? At least to have an idea...